# PHP if statement breaks webpage

Tags: php, html, if-statement, oscommerce

---

I didn't see an answer in a quick search, so I decided make a new one, I am on the checkout_shipping.php in OScommerce 2.3.4 and I am adding an if statement so that the value of $0.00 is the text "free" here is my code, it is incomplete because it is crashing the page, here is the code that I modified.

```
<?php
if ('cost' > 0) {
?>
<td><?php echo $currencies->format(tep_add_tax($quotes[$i]['methods'][$j]['cost'],       
(isset($quotes[$i]['tax']) ? $quotes[$i]['tax'] : 0))); ?></td>
<php
} ?>
```

fixed, it was syntax error; also cost wasn't a value, so I changed it to $i

Comment: `<php` should be `<?php`

Comment: `if ('cost' > 0) {` will always be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is your use of `<php` instead of `<?php`. But also the syntax of `if ('cost' > 0) {` makes no sense at all. So assuming `cost` is actually a variable named `$cost`, then this should work:

```
if ($cost > 0) {
?>
<td><?php echo $currencies->format(tep_add_tax($quotes[$i]['methods'][$j]['cost'],       
(isset($quotes[$i]['tax']) ? $quotes[$i]['tax'] : 0))); ?></td>
<?php
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are comparing 0 to a string, what you need to do is compare zero to a variable like so:

```
<?php

$count = 1;
if($count > 0) {
    //Do your logic here
}
```

Comment: Valid point, I up voted you. My page is now working perfectly.